# Count number of rows which satisfy a certain condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Often I need to count for how many rows a certain condition is satisfied. Currently I do that like this

```
select 
    groupCol, 
    sum(iif(myCondition, 1, 0)) conditionRows, 
    count(*) allRows 
from table 
group by groupCol
```

Is there a better way to do so? Maybe some built in function which does the job of `iif(myConditionB, 1, 0)` with only a single argument instead of three?

Comment: using `iif` is the most compact syntax, internally it's just expanded into a case expression anyway.

Comment: It's called a conditional aggregation.  Case or IIF() are essentially the same thing.

Comment: `count(case when myCondition then 1 end)` is the most idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

It is either you use CASE expression inside the COUNT to conditionally count rows where the Value column equals 0, alongside a total count of rows for each group. (like @Charlieface mentioned in the comment)

Or you can use SUM to calculate the conditionRows for each group like below :

- If the Value column for a row equals 0, the CASE expression returns 1
- If the Value column for a row does not equal 0, the CASE expression
  returns 0

```
CREATE TABLE ExampleTable (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    GroupCol NVARCHAR(50),
    Value INT
);
```

```
INSERT INTO ExampleTable (GroupCol, Value) VALUES
('Group1', 10),
('Group1', 20),
('Group1', 0), 
('Group2', 30),
('Group2', 0),
('Group2', 0), 
('Group3', 15),
('Group3', 25);
```

```
SELECT 
    groupCol, 
    SUM(CASE  WHEN  Value = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS conditionRows, 
    COUNT(*) AS allRows 
FROM 
        ExampleTable 
GROUP BY 
    groupCol
```

| groupCol | conditionRows | allRows |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Group1 | 1 | 3 |
| Group2 | 2 | 3 |
| Group3 | 0 | 2 |

```
SELECT 
    groupCol, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  Value = 0 THEN 1 END) AS conditionRows, 
    COUNT(*) AS allRows 
FROM 
    ExampleTable 
GROUP BY 
    groupCol
```

| groupCol | conditionRows | allRows |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Group1 | 1 | 3 |
| Group2 | 2 | 3 |
| Group3 | 0 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/z1dnysG3)

Comment: I believe COUNT is a bit faster than SUM since it doesn't actually have to do the math, but just check if there is a value. Personally I also prefer COUNT because it is more obvious I'm only doing a COUNT

Comment: @Stephan Is it? Internally, counting is summing ones as well.

Comment: Please feel free to validate, but I know I've tested it before years ago on a 2014 instance, tried it just now on a 2019 instance, found COUNT is about 5% faster (less CPU + faster execution) than SUM. I cannot speak to the raw internals of SQL Server , but logically COUNT IF EXISTS only need check for data, why SUM needs to interpret said data so it's logical there's a slight performance increase. See my query (used to Query Store to compare metrics) https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=cdae9546-aee9-4630-853a-631ee08dc3be